# Why Fixnum && Fixnum return the last number and not false?

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I've made an example:

```
if 22 && 2 == 2
  puts "true"
else
  puts "false"
end
```

on this code looks like it's the same as using only the number 2, and it's returning true, because obviously 2 is equal 2.

Comment: Same with JavaScript, Python and *many* dynamic languages.

Comment: What are you asking here? Why *would* your expression evaluate to `false`, in *any* language? I know of no languages where your `&&` would fail, implying  `22` or `2 == 2` are cast to boolean `false`. One is a non-zero number and one is boolean `true`.

Comment: I was thinking that 22 && 2 were comparing the both numbers, but that's not what's happening, i understand now after reading tadman's answer

Comment: You should interpret @meagar's comment, "What are you asking here?", as, "Please edit to state your question."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* thing in Ruby that's logically false are `nil` and `false`. Everything else, like `0`, empty strings, empty arrays, empty hashes, they're *all* considered logically true. This has implications for how Ruby handles boolean operators like `&&` and `||` since it doesn't need to force-cast things to a literal boolean value like `true` or `false`.

As such it's impossible for `22 && 2` to ever be logically false. The way the `&&` operator works is it returns the last element to break or confirm the evaluation:

```
1 && 2 && 3
# => 3
1 && false && 3
# => false
1 && 2 && nil
# => nil
```

The only way an `&&` operation will return `false` is if `false` is one of the two terms present. This can occur like this:

```
1 && !1
# => false
```

This is because `!1` evalutes as `false`.

You might be used to some languages where the result of `&&` is always a boolean value, but that's not the case here.

Update: What @meagar is pointing out here is your code is actually evaluated as this:

```
22 && (2 == 2)
```

Which is of course equivalent to:

```
22 && true
```

Which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: There is no `22 && 2` here. It's `22 && true`.

Comment: @meager Ah, due to [precedence rules](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) that appears to be correct.